# How to get a list of active PSTN calls in Teams using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We're looking for a way to get a list of all currently active PSTN calls being made into MS Teams. We've tried this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta

That's almost exactly what we need except records do not seem to appear here until the call has ended. What we need for the app we're trying to build is live call records.

We've also tried it by creating subscriptions and getting the ID of specific calls then looking up call records, but this data also appears to be delayed.

Is there a method we're missing here, or equally, is this something that may be added to the API some point soon?

Comment: AFAIK, i failed to see any feature is available at this point to get the active PSTN calls. May be you can file the uservoice for this, so that Teams can consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no graph API to get a list of active PSTN calls in Teams.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

They clearly mentioned in the document, we can not fetch the details directly. But you can fetch the records from your application. Using app side bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

**Function to get all results for PSTN and DirectRoutingCalls**

Function getvalue ($Uri, $Headers) {

```
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -Method Get
```

foreach ($entry in $results.Value)
{

```
     $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "userprincipalname" -Value $entry.userprincipalname
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "startDateTime" -Value $entry.startDateTime
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "endDateTime" -Value $entry.endDateTime
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "duration" -Value $entry.duration
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "callType" -Value $entry.callType
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "calleeNumber" -Value $entry.calleeNumber
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "callerNumber" -Value $entry.callerNumber
     $obj  |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "usageCountryCode" -Value $entry.usageCountryCode
    $obj | export-csv c:\Temp\${Outfile}.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
$queryURL = $results.'@odata.nextLink'
```

if ($results.'@odata.nextLink'.Length -ne 0) { $uri = "$queryURL"; getvalue $uri $Headers }
}

#PSTN URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=$startdate,toDateTime=$enddate)"
#Direct Routing URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime=$startdate,toDateTime=$enddate)"